# How do I install pine on a Mac?

Tags: unix

I'd like to install the Pine email client on Mac OS X 10.9.4. I've only ever used it as a pre-installed feature on Linux systems. I've tried downloading the file at http://www.washington.edu/pine/getpine/unix.html , and installing it using pip, but that doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/), I didn't find a recipe for pine, but I did find one for [Alpine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpine_(email_client)), which is "a rewrite of the Pine Message System that adds support for Unicode and other features".

```
$ brew install alpine
...
$ alpine
```

Answer (score 2):

There are instructions for setting up Pine on a Mac here:
http://www.novajo.ca/pine.html

Although, I am under the understanding that Pine is being discontinued and was replaced by Alpine - http://www.washington.edu/alpine/

Comment: Ah great, thanks. I tried the instructions for setting up Pine on a Mac and it seems that I am not able to use the wget command for some reason. I'm instead trying to directly install alpine from the binary, but am not sure how to install it, since it is not a mountable disk image file.